# Sourcing bashrc executes a function

Tags: bash, rc

I'm trying to define a convenience function to my `~/.bashrc`file and then source the file. However, when I `source ~/.bashrc` it executes the function I defined. What am I doing wrong? Here's the function:

```
# tensorflow object detection train call
train_net()
{
        python /root/training/model_main.py \
        --pipeline_config_path=/root/training/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config \
        --model_dir=/root/training/models \
        --num_train_steps=100000 \
        --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
        --logtostderr=true
}
```

Hmmm. Okay thanks, will fix this post to align with minimal/complete example as soon as a process is finished running. Btw my entire `~/.bashrc` is

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
export PYTHONPATH=/tensorflow/models/research:/tensorflow/models/research/slim

export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1

jp()
{
        jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --port=8888
}

jl()
{
    jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --port=8888
}

# Run from the tensorflow/models/research/ directory
train_net()
{
    python /root/training/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=/root/training/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config \
    --model_dir=/root/training/models \
    --num_train_steps=100000 \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
    --logtostderr=true
}

# Run from the tensorflow/models/research/ directory
eval_net()
{
    python /root/training/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=/root/training/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config \
    --model_dir=/root/training/models \
    --checkpoint_dir=/root/training/models/train \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
    --eval_training_data=False \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=5 \
    --logtostderr=true
}

# Run TensorBoard
tb(){
    tensorboard --logdir=/root/training/models
}
```

Comment: That definition alone doesn't execute anything; the problem is elsewhere. Testing that the code included in the question is sufficient to cause a bug *on its own* is part of the process for building a [mcve].

Comment: That said, I would suggest logging your shell's startup process to figure out where the problem *really* lives. Inspecting the logs generated by `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l` (and again with `-i` instead of `-l` if the issue doesn't trigger) would be a good place to start.

Comment: ...well. That definition alone doesn't execute anything, *if it's run in a shell in blank/default state*. If you're in an environment that, say, already defined an alias under the same name as the function, there you go -- but, see again re: MCVE rules (since were that the case, you'd be posting a question without sufficient code to trigger the bug included).

Comment: A good place to start to test whether you provided an adequate reproducer, btw, is running the code from your question in an online interpreter. See https://ideone.com/D62WAs invoking the exact code provided here -- no attempt to run Python takes place.

Comment: Thanks, will try to minimize my example shortly

Comment: Any luck at that? There's a lot of code in the full `.bashrc` that evaluates external content -- source'ing `conda` subcommands, the `lesspipe` activation bits, the `.bash_aliases` file included by reference, etc; hard to make conclusive statements about behavior of a script where portions are external to the provided text.

Comment: Unfortunately I have an object detection script still training so I'm afraid that experimenting with the bashrc file at the moment might crash my training, but as soon as it finishes I'm going to start pulling things out of my bashrc and re sourcing it to narrow down the issue

Comment: As a plug for a toolkit I'm rather enamored with right now, at some point you might find it interesting to look at [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) -- instead of having just one environment that needs to have all your tools in it, you can create a `shell.nix` file for each project describing which tools you want in your PATH; think of it like a Python virtualenv but for the whole operating system (you can say "for this project, I want jq 1.5, Python 3.6 with libraries X, Y and Z, libjpeg version 1.2.3 compiled with gcc 7.2", and then have different software specified for a separate project).

Comment: ...point being that that way you don't have just one big global set of user configuration you need to worry about keeping in consistent and working order across all your projects.